# How to check template on safari desktop and mobile without mac?

Tags: responsive-webdesign, safari

I am developing a HTML/CSS template. I am using Fedora Linux platform to write codes and test pages.
For test my template on safari (especially mobile version) I have some trouble without any apple device.
I want to know how to test properly my template output like its real output on apple desktops or mobiles?

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

1. Buy some Apple devices just for testing.
2. [Install Safari on Linux using Wine](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-ease-your-browser-compatibility-testing-efforts/) and trust that mobile devices work enough like it.
3. Subscribe to a cloud-based browser testing service that lets you view any URL on a variety of actually web browsers and devices.  Here is [an article that lists 10 of them and what features they offer](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-ease-your-browser-compatibility-testing-efforts/).

I have personally chosen to use the third option.  I pay $300 USD per year for one of those services and always have access to whatever browsers I need to test my websites.  That ends up being way cheaper than buying my own devices and its a lot less hassle than trying to install a variety of browsers and mobile simulators locally.